# Running Espresso tests on Android 4.4?

Tags: android, gradle, junit4, android-espresso, ui-testing

I'm trying to migrate our app to using Espresso for UI testing, but I'm unable to make Gradle find my tests with a device running Android 4.4 (API 19, our minimum deployment target). Tests on Android 6.0 (API 23) run fine. I added the JUnit runner and the dependencies to `app/build.gradle` according to [this](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html#download-espresso) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTestingEspresso/article.html#espresso_using) (I excluded annotations because of version conflicts between the modules):

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
...
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
...
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2") {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test:runner:0.5") {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test:rules:0.5") {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
```

Then I created the required directory structure `app/src/androidTest/java/` and a package `com.companyname.appname` and a java class `EspressoTest.java` with some mock test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EspressoTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TermsOfUse> termsOfUseActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TermsOfUse.class);

    @Test
    public void iAmAtTouView() {
        onView(withId(R.id.terms_of_use_content)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

If I right-click on the test class `EspressoTest` and choose "Run 'EspressoTest'" I get an error:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e package com.companyname.appname -e debug false com.companyname.appname.qa.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
Empty test suite.
```

Also if I enter `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` in the command line I get:

```
Starting 0 tests on GT-I9305 - 4.4.4
Tests on GT-I9305 - 4.4.4 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[GT-I9305 - 4.4.4] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
:app:connectedAuditDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedAuditDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: 
...
```

So to me it seems like Gradle doesn't recognize my test class when trying to execute test tasks with an Android device. How can I fix this?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you had to enable multidex, because your `*-androidTest.apk` contained more than 64k methods?

If so, you need to make sure that the first dex file (`classes.dex`) contains all the `*Test` classes that you want to run. You can configure this like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
    }
}
```

and in your `multidex-config.pro` you add regular `-keep` rules for your test classes, e.g.

```
-keep class path.to.my.package.**.*Test { *; }
```

If your test classes have dependencies outside of your own package path, be sure to include those as well with separate `-keep` statements. Look out for `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` in `adb logcat` to identify missing classes.

Answer (score 0):

First check what tasks are avaliable for gradle to run by:

```
gradle <app-module>:tasks
```

or

```
gradle --gui
```

See if the task you are running is in the list of tasks. Also which machine are you trying to run: MacOS or Windows? Always run gradle with 'sudo' if not at least sync your project from android studio always a good idea before running the tests

Comment: The task is in the list, and as you can see from the console output I posted it is run by Gradle. Otherwise I would get an exception saying task not found. I am on Mac OS, and I never run anything with sudo unless explicitly required by the interface.

Comment: Kill your Android Studio and then re-open it and try to run it. Just give it a try

Comment: I edited the original post to clarify that the tests fail on Android 4.4, not on 6.0.

Comment: Yes that happens did you try running the tests with or without @Test annotations? also when you add or remove always gradle clean and then run tests. Try that

Answer (score 0):

Added additional info for Thomas Keller's answer:

```
-keep path.to.my.package.**.*Test { *; }
```

has syntax error, it should be:

```
-keep class path.to.my.package.**.*Test { *; }
```

According to Android guide:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?#multidexkeepproguard-property

It worked for me. I run instrument test on Android 4.4.

When I found the key message in logcat that the test runner only search classpath in the main DEX path, even though the secondary dex is already processed by `androidx.multidex`.

```
D/dalvikvm( 7758): DexOpt: --- END 'com.byted.bytexx.test-1.apk.classes2.zip' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm( 7758): DEX prep '/data/data/com.byted.bytexx.test/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.byted.bytexx.test-1.apk.classes2.zip': unzip in 109ms, rewrite 1745ms
I/MultiDex( 7758): install done
I/MonitoringInstr( 7758): Instrumentation started!
I/MultiDex( 7758): Installing instrumentation
I/MultiDex( 7758): Installation done

...

I/TestRequestBuilder( 7758): Scanning classpath to find tests in paths [/data/app/com.byted.bytexx.test-1.apk]

...

D/TestExecutor( 7758): Adding listener androidx.test.internal.runner.listener.ActivityFinisherRunListener
I/TestRunner( 7758): run started: 1 tests
I/TestRunner( 7758): run finished: 0 tests, 0 failed, 0 ignored
I/MonitoringInstr( 7758): waitForActivitiesToComplete() took: 0ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 7741): Shutting down VM
```

And I found my test code is not in the main DEX.